# Connecting to a network printer through a wireless AP

Tags: wifi, network-printer

I have a network printer connected to a cisco RV082. I also have another wireless router connected to the RV082 as an wireless access point.

Accessing the internet through wireless were fine. I just get a problem that i can't print the document through the wireless network.

Any Computer directly connected to the RV082 were fine in printing.

Is there anything i have to set up in both the RV082 and the wireless router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop routing with the router that you're using as an AP. That's the simplest way.

Comment: Exactly. Use it only as an access point. (Turn off its DHCP server, don't use its WAN/Internet port, and so on.)